# Access violation error when calling glGetString

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl-2, glad

I'm creating an OpenGL application in C++ using SDL2 + GLAD. In my main function, I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL.h>

#include <glad\glad.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) {
        std::cout << "SDL could not be initialized.";
        return 1;
    }

    SDL_GL_LoadLibrary(nullptr);

    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_ACCELERATED_VISUAL, 1);

    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4);

    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 5);

    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 24);

    SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow("Hello world", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 500, 500, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);

    if (window == nullptr) {
        std::cout << "SDL could not open window";
        return 1;
    }

    const SDL_GLContext context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);

    if (context == nullptr) {
        std::cout << "SDL could not create context";
        return 1;
    }

    printf("OpenGL loaded\n");

    printf("Vendor:          %s\n", glGetString(GL_VENDOR));
    printf("Renderer:        %s\n", glGetString(GL_RENDERER));
    printf("Version OpenGL:  %s\n", glGetString(GL_VERSION));
    printf("Version GLSL:    %s\n", glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION));

    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);

    int w, h;
    SDL_GetWindowSize(window, &w, &h);
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    SDL_Event event;
    bool quit = false;
    while (!quit) {
        SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT) {
                quit = true;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

However, when I run this, I'm receiving the following error:

```
Exception thrown at 0x0000000000000000 in TestApp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x0000000000000000.
```

The `OpenGL loaded` message is printed, and Visual Sutio shows that the error is thrown on the `printf("Vendor:%s\n", glGetString(GL_VENDOR));` line.

I've made sure to link SDL2 and GLAD correctly in the properties window for the solution. What could be causing this error?

Comment: "*using SDL2 + GLAD*" So... where do you include GLAD?

Comment: Can you provide a call stack for the exception thrown?

Comment: https://github.com/Dav1dde/glad have a usage example. You have to call `gladLoadGL` before using any function provided by glad. Right now you're calling null.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Glad](https://glad.dav1d.de/) Loader-Generator has to be initialized by either [`gladLoadGL`](https://github.com/Dav1dde/glad/blob/master/README.md) or [`gladLoadGLLoader`](https://github.com/Dav1dde/glad/blob/master/README.md), right after creating and making current the OpenGL context by [`SDL_GL_CreateContext`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GL_CreateContext).

See also [OpenGL Loading Library - glad](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library#glad_.28Multi-Language_GL.2FGLES.2FEGL.2FGLX.2FWGL_Loader-Generator.29)

e.g.:

```cpp
const SDL_GLContext context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);
if (context == nullptr) {
    std::cout << "SDL could not create context";
    return 1;
}

if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)SDL_GL_GetProcAddress))
{
    std::cout << "Failed to initialize OpenGL context" << std::endl;
    return -1;
}

printf("OpenGL loaded\n");

printf("Vendor:          %s\n", glGetString(GL_VENDOR));
printf("Renderer:        %s\n", glGetString(GL_RENDERER));
printf("Version OpenGL:  %s\n", glGetString(GL_VERSION));
printf("Version GLSL:    %s\n", glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION));
```

Answer (score 0):

If an error is generated, `glGetString` returns 0.
And then `printf` is try access memory at address 0.
Or `glGetString` is not available because OpenGL library is not loaded.
So there probably you have some issue with initialization OpenGL.
Try specify full path to OpenGL DLL module in `SDL_GL_LoadLibrary`

Please make sure `SDL_GL_LoadLibrary` is return 0, otherwise call `SDL_GetError()` for more information.